# Why is CGI not showing labels for input fields

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I'm a greenhorn in perl CGI and want to create a CGI form for user input. The problem is that the code is not outputting the field names.

Here is the code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -T

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use CGI;
my $cgi = CGI->new;
print $cgi->header(),
$cgi->start_html(
    -title => "my form",
),
$cgi->p(scalar localtime),

$cgi->p("welcome to myform"),
$cgi->start_form({
    -action =>"",
    -method =>"",
});
print $cgi->textfield({
    -label => "Username :",
    -type => 'text',
    -size=>30,});

$cgi->end_form(),

$cgi->end_html();
```

In the above case I want the html output to show the label for the username.

Comment: In the above case i want the html output toshow the label for the username

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`CGI`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI) module doesn't support a `-label` attribute for `textfield` elements. Instead you have to enclose it in a separate `<label>` element, like this

```
print $cgi->label(
  'Username :',
  $cgi->textfield({
    -type => 'text',
    -size=>30,})
);
```

But please also note the warning ***HTML Generation functions should no longer be used*** in [the module's own documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI#HTML-Generation-functions-should-no-longer-be-used).

> All HTML generation functions within CGI.pm are no longer being maintained. Any issues, bugs, or patches will be rejected unless they relate to fundamentally broken page rendering.
>
> The rationale for this is that the HTML generation functions of CGI.pm are an obfuscation at best and a maintenance nightmare at worst. You should be using a template engine for better separation of concerns. See [CGI::Alternatives](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI::Alternatives) for an example of using CGI.pm with the [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Toolkit) module.

Comment: Thankyou for the solution. Thank you also for the headsup on CGI

Comment: I'm pleased to help. I think it's important that you avoid CGI if you possibly can, especially as you have only just started learning it. [`Dancer2`](https://metacpan.org/release/Dancer2) with [`Template::Toolkit`](https://metacpan.org/module/Template::Toolkit) is much simpler to write (although it may not seem so because of the vast range of possibilities). You should look at [`CGI::Alternatives`](https://metacpan.org/module/CGI::Alternatives) to get a better idea of what is available.

Comment: The alternatives look quite complicated i must admit